# Do Apache connections limit the amount of php sessions

Tags: apache-2.2, php

My host is saying that maximum number of Apache connections is limited to 30. Does this mean I can't maintain more than 30 php sessions at a time?

Answer (score 2):

No.  PHP sessions are (by default) file based, so you can have as many of them as can fit on your server's disk.

Answer (score 2):

No, this exactly means that there can't be more than 30 simultaneous connections.

Http session is basically series of http requests with common state that is kept on server (and which is actually called 'session').
Session lifetime is decoupled from connection lifetime, i.e. session can last within single connection (as if keep-alive is set, so each connection is used to process series of requests), can span on multiple connections (as of modern browsers can open multiple connections to single resource to increase page load speed) or else, more than 30 sessions can be handled within 30 connections provided that at any time there won't be more than 30 parties that are talking to server (for example, with forbidden keep-alive on server, so that after serving request apache will force connection to close and thus freeing slot for next request, possibly belonging to another user session; however, disabling keep-alive is not good choice for performance as it increases overhead on connection establishment).

Comment: SO, this 30 simultaneous connections would be enough for an average site?

Comment: This depends on load but 30 seems to be rather low value as for me.